# mediaremoted gives property list error in iOS5

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios5

I have an app I'm migrating to iOS5, when running in the simulator, I see a slew of messages like this:

```
10/25/11 10:34:43.002 AM mediaremoted: Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain NULL)
10/25/11 10:34:43.003 AM mediaremoted: Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain NULL)
```

being issued right after I load a movie into a MPMoviePlayerViewController with the following code:

```
if (moviePath)
{
  movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

  // this next line will throw these messages
  MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

  [view presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
  [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setMoviePlayerVC:mpvc];

}
```

it's not at all clear to me what "property list" is responsible for this error message, as none seems to being read at this point. I'm inclined to believe that this may be a red-herring.  Any thoughts would be helpful

Comment: Can you post the code where you get the moviePath ? Also are you registering for any movie player notifications ?